# How prove this ineqlity

Tags: inequality

Let $x,y,z,w>0$ and such that $xyzw=1$. Show that
$$
\dfrac{1+x}{1+x^2}+\dfrac{1+y}{1+y^2}+\dfrac{1+z}{1+z^2}+\dfrac{1+w}{1+w^2}\le 4.
$$

Comment: That would be my guess as well,but I didn't have time to attempt an answer.

Comment: Observe that $\dfrac{x}{1+x^2} \leq \dfrac{1}{2}$ and for the remaining part, note that $\dfrac{1}{1+x}+\dfrac{1}{1+y} \leq \dfrac{1}{1+xy}+1$.